# processing uploads without reaching timeout limit

Tags: php, ajax, timeout

currently i have an import script which needs to be able to load up to 500k rows from a csv file. i have the upload script ready, but the page times out at around 13k uploaded rows. the file however will continue importing it, and ill be stuck without getting a report for it.

how could i make sure that the page doesnt timeout in the browser after x amount of minutes?
the company i work for have it like the process happens somewhere else and i just get the report of the features completed. however i cant ask them for it (because they refuse to tell me anything about it) and i dont know myself how its done.

im thinking about either increasing the timeout of the page (if possible) to like 2 hours or maybe something with ajax which sends data from another page to the page im viewing so it doesnt timeout?
how would/could this be done, or do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',0);
```

add above code in first line of your upload script.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase file uploading file size and execution time.

go to `wamp\bin\php\phpx.x.xx` find php.ini and make following changes

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M 
;or whatever size you want

max_execution_time = 60
; you can increase as you want. this is in seconds
```